# Writing an element on each row of a new sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a data array. I would like to write each element of the array onto a row in a new sheet. In addition, I would like each element within an element to be in the next cell along. I'm not sure about how I go about doing this.

I think that a nested for loop might be solution which is what I have tried below. It manages to print each element onto the Logger; now I just need a way to write it to a spreadsheet in rows.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var data = [['Mr. Gerald', 'Monday', '2:10'], ['Mr. Holmes', 'Tuesday', '3:00']]
  var dataSheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
  var startRange = dataSheet.getRange(1,1)

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length;i++) {
    for (var a = 0; a<data[i].length; a++) {
      Logger.log(data[i][a])
    }}  
}
```

[The output should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZeuG.png)

Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `data` is in the actual format that's required in the sheet:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var data = [['Mr. Gerald', 'Monday', '2:10'], 
              ['Mr. Holmes', 'Tuesday', '3:00']];
  var dataSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  dataSheet.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data); //or use Advanced Google Services    
}
```

If `data` is not of square/rectangular shape, Use [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#writing_to_a_single_range):

```
  var request = {
    range: dataSheet.getName() + '!A1',
    majorDimension: 'ROWS',
    values: data,
  };
  //API must be enabled before use. 
  //https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update(request, ss.getId(), request.range, {
    valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED',
  });
```

Comment: Thank you, do you know how this part 'data[0].length' will need to change in cases where the an element in an array has 2 and not always 3 elements within it. For example, [['Mr. Gerald', 'Monday', '2:10'], ['Mr. Holmes', 'Tuesday']]?

Comment: @LMACK  Number of elements in each array must be equal. If it's 2 in array2, it should  also be 2 in array1. Only matrix can be set using `setValues()`. You need to add a empty string to array2 or use  Advanced Google services(sheets API), where no such restrictions apply.